# Проблема с подключением, не видно порты

Tags: сеть, port

На удаленном пк стоит IIS, и PostgreSQL, netstat и ipconfig /all, говорят что порты открыты, но при сканировании портов видно что открыты только порты IIS(80, 443), а другие порты нет. На пк не стоит никакой файрвол, Брандмаауэр. СУБД настроена правильно, все работало, ничего нового не ставилось, и недавно все оборвалось, что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно понять, что стоит между Вами и нужным Вам компьютером. Возможно, между вами стоит сетевой экран и там настроен проброс только стандартных портов.

> и недавно все оборвалось

Не вносили ли изменения в сеть недавно, такие как установка нового оборудования, роутеров, изменение маршрутизации и т.п.? Вполне возможно, что вносили и не прописали правила.